# Feedback Form HTML Unexpected end of file PHP

Tags: html, file, post, printing

This php file appears correct, but is returning an 'unexpected end of file' error.  Is the error somewhere in the html file.  I have tried putting the tags inside print in "", removed one extra white space on the php line, added white spaces between the brackets[] and quotes'' on the variable lines, and still have the same error when I press enter to send the data to the php script.  Here is the html code:  http://pastebin.com/Rb62pZcy

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Your Feedback</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php // Script 3.3 handle_form.php
// This page receives the data from feedback.html
// It will receive: title, name, email, comments in $_POST

$title = $_POST [ 'title' ] ;
$name = $_POST [ 'name' ] ;
$email = $_POST [ 'email' ] ;
$comments = $_POST [ 'comments' ] ;

print "<p>Thank you, $title $name, for your comments.</p>"
"<p>You stated that you found this example to be '$response' and added:<br />$comments</p>"

?>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
print "<p>Thank you, $title $name, for your comments.</p>"
"<p>You stated that you found this example to be '$response' and added:<br />$comments</p>"
```

Use this:

```
echo "<p>Thank you, $title $name, for your comments.</p>";
echo "<p>You stated that you found this example to be '$response' and added:<br />$comments</p>";
```

I think you miss the ";" character.

------------------UPDATE-----------------------------

I try this code and works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Your Feedback</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php 

    if (isset($_POST['email'])){
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    }
    else
    {
     $title = "No title arrived";
     $name = "No name arrived";
     $comments = "No comments arrived";
    }

    //$response is not defined??
    $response = "Live long and prosper";
    //so i defined

    echo "<p>Thank you, $title $name, for your comments.</p>";
    echo "<p>You stated that you found this example to be '$response' and added:<br />$comments</p>";
    ?>
    </body>

    </html>
```

PS: try executing this script alone...name it "handle_form.php" and put this in the nav address bar:

```
localhost/your_project/handle_form.php
```

Works on my localhost.....if your problem continue then may be the problem is in the submit page.

Saludos.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried what you suggested, and it is giving the same error.